# UART - do not show response

Tags: c, serial-port, uart

I am using below code on my raspberry pi. I made phisical connection between lines TX and RX.

```
#include <termios.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/signal.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


#define BAUDRATE B9600
#define PORT "/dev/ttyAMA0"
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1


void signal_handler_IO ( int status );   // definition of signal handler        
volatile int STOP = FALSE;         
int wait_flag = TRUE;                  // TRUE while no signal received


int main()
{
    int fd, res, sen;
    int i;
    struct termios oldtio, newtio;
    struct sigaction saio; /* definition of signal action */
    char comm[10]="12345\n";
    char    resp[10];

   /* open the device to be non-blocking (read will return immediatly) */
    fd = open( PORT, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );

    if (fd < 0) { perror(PORT); return 1; }


    /* install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
    saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
     //saio.sa_mask = 0;
     saio.sa_flags = 0;
     saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
     sigaction( SIGIO, &saio, NULL );

    /* allow the process to receive SIGIO */
     fcntl( fd, F_SETOWN, getpid() );
     /* Make the file descriptor asynchronous (the manual page says only 
        O_APPEND and O_NONBLOCK, will work with F_SETFL...) */
     fcntl( fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC );


    //tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */ 
    /* set new port settings for canonical input processing */

    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    //newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR; 
    newtio.c_oflag = 0; 
    newtio.c_lflag = ICANON; 
    //newtio.c_lflag = 0; 
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; 
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH); 
    tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &newtio );

    printf("Write start...\n"); 

    sen = write( fd, comm, 8);

    printf("Write stop...\n %s sen = %d\n", comm,sen);


    printf("Read start...\n");

    res = read( fd, resp, 8 );

    printf("Read stop...\n");

    resp[res] = '\0';

    printf("Response = %s, how much bytes %d\n", resp,res );


    /* restore old port settings */ 
    tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio );

  return 0;

}


 /***************************************************************************
 * signal handler. sets wait_flag to FALSE, to indicate above loop that     *
 * characters have been received.                                           *
 ***************************************************************************/      
void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
    printf("received SIGIO signal.\n");
    wait_flag = FALSE;
}
```

But when i lunch it is see:

Write start...
Write stop...
12345
sen = 8
Read start...
recieved SIGIO signal.
Read stop...
Response = 
, how much bytes 6

The problem is that i do not see any response string. I'm recieving 6 bytes like i send. I see new line like it was on comm[10]="12345\n";

What can i do?

I made also test with minicom:
When i lunch:
minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0

and on the other terminal window i write:
printf '12345' > /dev/ttyAMA0

I got it on minicom screen when TX and RX are connected.
Is it ok?

Comment: What _is_ actually received? You could try dumping the string as hex instead.

Comment: i made printf("%x",resp) and still i see only new line character (the cursor goes to new line. But it counts well - i am sending 6 bytes and recieving 6 bytes... i do not get it...

Comment: You should read [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html), and always call `tcgetattr()` to properly setup attributes.  You should not set `VMIN` and `VTIME` in canonical mode.  You are not showing all of your code, and there's probably a loop that is contributing to your problem: you're probably seeing only the last byte received in your buffer (and discarding earlier data).  Try removing the `O_NONBLOCK` option, since you are not handling it properly.